# The breakdown voltage of APDs

Tags: photodiode, avalanche-breakdown

what does the breakdown voltage of an APD tell me? I know certain methods how to determine it but, what happens after reaching that point?
More specific: Is the gain afterwards constant or still rising?

Comment: google "Geiger mode APD" or "SPAD APD" for details.  "gain" really becomes a bit meaningless because a single photon can trigger an avalanche, but the design has to have provisions for quenching the potential for runaway avalanches and usually requires cooling to reduce dark current noise (which can also trigger the device).

Answer (score 1):

The breakdown voltage is the bias voltage at which a single charge carrier (usually an electron) can initiate avalanche breakdown. Avalanche breakdown is when the charge carriers have enough kinetic energy to create additional charge carriers upon impact with the semiconductor lattice. The additional charge carriers are created because the impact gives them enough energy to escape from the lattice.

After the breakdown voltage, the APD is no longer operating in linear mode, i.e., there is no relation like (output current) = (gain)x(photosensitivity)x(input light). Instead, a single charge will result in a rapidly increasing current that is either intentionally quenched or the APD is destroyed. This operation is non-linear: there is a term called *saturation* that describes the effect of incident photons being ignored while the APD is in avalanche breakdown because the APD current is dominated by the avalanche effect.

A quick internet search will give you more detail than this and have helpful diagrams.